# In Arrow's theorem, why not $n=2$?

Tags: economics, voting-theory, social-choice-theory

In the statement of [Arrow's impossibility theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem), why do we omit the case $n=2$?

I will appreciate it if you can explain it in easy words. I'm by no means an expert in the area (I think it's very much clear from the question too :) )

Answer (score 1):

It's false in the case $n=2$ - just pick the standard voting model (sum up the votes between the two candidates), and it satisfies all three of Arrow's axioms, which you can check.

Answer (score 1):

When there are only two candidates, simple majority rules -- i.e., neither candidate can win with less than half the vote.

A little more technically, the three conditions of Arrow's theorem (unanimity, non-dictatorship, and independence of irrelevant alternatives) are not incompatible.  In particular, independence of irrelevant alternatives is automatically satisfied:  If alternatives $a$ and $b$ have the same rankings in $(R_1,\ldots,R_N)$ and $(S_1,\ldots,S_N)$, and if $a$ and $b$ are the *only* alternatives, then $(R_1,\ldots,R_N)=(S_1,\ldots,S_N)$ and hence $F(R_1,\ldots,R_N)=F(S_1,\ldots,S_N)$ no matter what $F$ is.